# Find the Logical Inconsistency

Tags: proof-verification, fake-proofs

Recently one of my friend came up with something which he claimed to be a proof of the famous Legendre Conjecture. Let me brief his argument.

> **Statement of The Conjecture**
>
> There exists at least one prime between two consecutive squares.
>
> **Proof**
>
> If there existed at least one prime between two consecutive squares and if $n^2$ would be the $k$-th composite, denoted by $C$ $(k)$ then Legendre's Conjecture says that $(n+1)^2$ is impossible to become $C$ $(k+2n+1)$ . So the goal now is to find $k$ 's so that
>
> $C$ $(k+2n+1)$ $-$ $C$ $(k)$ $>$ $2n+1$
>
> Now from find the bound of $n$ and then maintaining the bound find all possible $n$ (his claim was this will be all integers because of the bound, and I think here is the mistake but still it is my guess, still no rigorous proof of this assertion is in my hand) and when you find those $n$ the conjecture is proved.

Let me tell now why I think that there must be something wrong in the 'proof'. Right now I can think of only two reasons.

1. Though it will not be logical to say but I think that the problem which has baffled so many mathematicians for so many years, is  unlikely to be solved in this way.
2. I doubt about the correctness of the method of obtaining the bound.

Comment: Any proof of $X$ that starts "if $X$" is immediately suspect. You're not to assume your conclusion.

Comment: @Gerry. I don't think there is any mistake at least in the way you told. If you read that 'proof' you will see that the argument investigates what happens if Legendre Conjecture is true, and then seeks to investigate the cases when this is true. I think there is no mistake in examining the conditions under which $X$ is true. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's really simple: you can't prove $X$ by starting, "if $X$". I could prove $1=2$, if you let me start my proof with "If $1=2$". If you can't rewrite the "proof" without it starting by assuming its conclusion, then you don't have a proof.

Comment: @Gerry. Sorry, I really don't understand your argument. Let me come to your example, if you investigate under what conditions $1=2$ then you find that under no conditions it is true because mathematical system is free from contradiction. The method that my friend adopted is probably one similar to this. If you don't mind then can you site an example of a proof the argument structure of which is similar to that of my friends but it yields a contradiction?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to say but you are still wrong. What your friend did was not that he proved $A$, but he proved a consequence of $A$. This is not a proof of $A$, however. For example, if there is a finite amount of prime numbers, there must be an infinite number of composite numbers. Now, just because there really is an infinite number of composite numbers, that does not mean I have proven that there are a finite number of primes.

Comment: @5xum. Now I see what has gone wrong with my friend's argument. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the Legendre conjecture starts with "if the Legendre conjecture is true". Therefore, it is of the form "if A, then something something something then A", which can be shortened into "if A, then A".